# Go back 2 pages - React-Router - ReactJS -

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an component that it goBack to the previous page. I use that: `this.props.history.goBack();` but I wanna that go back two levels. I have tried a lot of thing as `this.props.history.goBack(-2);` but I do not achieve that. I am using ReactRouter v4.

How could I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `this.props.history.go(-2)`

as it's described in 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md

Comment: I have used it but.. `goBack()` do not re-render all page... and `go(-2)` re-render all page... Do you know how solve that?

Comment: is it the re-render matter ? i mean just control your store's state, and the page will be same as it is. or may you can to use [react-undo](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-undo)

Comment: I am not using Redux. But page may not be reloaded. Other way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with Redux. `this.props.history.go` is using `window.history` instead of Redux